# Edge+Firefox height issue with nested flex

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I've been working on a Flexbox layout (using Bootstrap 4) even though I should probably be using CSS Grid at this point.  I had it working great in Chrome/FF/Edge until I added 1 more level of nesting, which then throws off the `height: 100%` calculation only in Firefox and Edge (which is basically just an older version of Chrome now).

I was under the impression as long as the parents are `display: flex` and `height: 100%` that I could rely on the child height being calculated correctly (meaning 100% of the remaining flexible height).

This variation works:

- https://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/cLpj0d1y/5/
- ```
  <!-- good -->
  <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100" style="overflow: auto;">
    <div>
      content here
    </div>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9
  </div>
  ```
- [image]

This variation spills over into the body, exposing scrollbars:

- https://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/cLpj0d1y/6/
- [image]
- ```
  <!-- bad -->
  <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <div class="h-100" style="overflow: auto;">
      <div>
        content here
      </div>
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

See the `<!-- good -->` vs `<!- bad -->` HTML blocks.

Am I missing something simple or is this a bug or limitation in Flexbox with Firefox/Edge?

I'm using more elements than necessary, but need to because I'm using AngularJS components.

Comment: The additional element activates the `min-height: auto` default on flex items, forcing the div to overflow the parent. Simply add `min-height: 0` to the overflowing item, which overrides the default. Details are in the duplicate. https://jsfiddle.net/a10n9s2b/